# print tuple as number of arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass the variadic number of arguments and then print them (if some conditions are true).
When I try to do so:

```
def my_print(*args)
    print args
```

It prints a tuple. How do I make python act `my_print(a,b)` as `print a,b` ?

Comment: @Mark: it's simple log function. Acts as print if error log level is high enough for this message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x you can use `str.join`:

```
def my_print(*args):
    print ' '.join(map(str, args))
```

If you are using Python 3.x then it's even easier because there's a `print` function:

```
def my_print(*args):
    print(*args)
```

Other answers also mention that you can `from __future__ import print_function`, but this has the disadvantage that all your existing code that uses the `print` statement will break.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(*args)
```

This gets you the 3.x style print function so you can unpack the arguments. Do note that you then need to use the 3.x syntax everywhere in that module, however.

Comment: That's great, but I'm not going to change all code. So, +1, but accept to Mark

Answer (score 0):

Use builtin print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

my_print = print
```

Or

```
my_print = getattr(__builtins__, 'print')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for _ in len(range(args)):
    print a[_],
```

But it looks like the other answers are more correct